# Undo the DISABLE PK CASCADE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I had to use temporally the enabling cascade to fix some problems in my DB.
I used this alter:

```
ALTER TABLE table
DISABLE PRIMARY KEY CASCADE;
```

And now I'd want to undo it and enable all the constraints again. Have I got to enable them one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any way of automatic enabling constraints in a cascade way, even tried to google that but no results of any value.
So this is what I would do:
Go and ask dba_constraints for all constraints referencing this primary key:

```
select *
  from dba_constraints
connect by prior constraint_name = r_constraint_name
 start with constraint_name = '<your_primary_key_constraint>';
```

Just double check that those are the ones you should enable and create a script to enable them all:

```
select 'alter table ' || table_name || ' enable ' || constraint_name || ';'
  from dba_constraints
connect by prior constraint_name = r_constraint_name
 start with constraint_name = '<your_primary_key_constraint>'
 where c.status = 'DISABLED';
```

and just run it...

Comment: The general idea is the correct one.  But just a thought: I believe that the `DISABLE ... CASCADE` doesn't recursively disable all the dependent foreign keys.  I think it only disables *direct* dependencies.  So you may not need to use a `connect by`.  I didn't dig too deep, so I could be wrong.

Comment: hmm, I believe you're right and I just rushed with connect by on that :) you can go with all the constraints having r_constraint_name of your primary key and create a script for that...

Comment: Both of you shed light on the real impossibility of what I wanted, but I can choose only one answer, and I chose this one, for being faster, but I upvoted @sstan's because was very convincing. Thank you two.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to re-enable the the dependent constraints one by one.  There is no magic `cascade` option for the re-enabling of the constraint.

Here is a quote from Darl Kuhn's "Pro Oracle Database 12c Administration" book. The information applies to Oracle 11g as well:

> Keep in mind that there is no `ENABLE ... CASCADE` statement. To reenable the constraints, you have to query the data dictionary to determine which constraints have been disabled and then reenable them individually.

In line with that quote, `przemo_pl` has provided you a good answer to minimize the pain of handling your use case.